# Regressing two multi-dimensional data sets?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, regression, linear-regression

Assume I have two data sets, `X1` and `X2`, each of dimensions N-by-D, where N is the number of samples and D is the number of dimensions of the data set.

In my current project, `X1` and `X2` are the same dataset at different stages of an operation (say, `X1` first, `X2` later). I am seeking a simple way to determine at which point the operation no longer induces any significant changes on `X2`. If the datasets were one-dimensional, a simple way to achieve this would be to regress `X1` and `X2` against each other, then check how close the r value is to 1.

However, if both `X1`and `X2` are multi-dimensional, I don't know how to implement this anymore. I assume I could regress each pair of dimensions independently, then average the results, but that feels like a hack. Do you know how I can calculate a multi-dimensional equivalent to the `r` value in Python?

*Edit*: As opposed to the example below, the samples in both data sets correspond to one another. I am essentially just seeking a way to quantify how much change (if any) the operation which takes X1 to X2 induces.

Here is a simple setup as a basis:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set the dimensions
N   = 100
D   = 3

# Create two correlated datasets
cov = np.identity(D*2)
cov[3,0] = 0.5
cov[4,1] = 0.5
cov[5,2] = 0.5
cov[0,3] = 0.5
cov[1,4] = 0.5
cov[2,5] = 0.5
X   = scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.rvs(
    mean    = np.zeros(D*2),
    cov     = cov,
    size    = N)

# Extract the two correlated datasets
X1  = X[:,:D]
X2  = X[:,D:]
```

Comment: Maybe I understand you wrong, but I feel like you are mixing two things. The one is the influence of X on Y and the other is a significant difference between Y1 and Y2.
You regress X on Y to determine the influnce of exogene variables on Y, but to see if something changed between Stage 1 and Stage 2, you would compare the distributions of Y1 and Y2, with a two group t-test

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow... Perhaps some background: In my case, the specific application is Bayesian smoothing. In essence, once you get a new data point, you update the past states as well by moving backwards through the time series. At some point, the "new" information is independent of the older time steps, so the operation from X1 to X2 is the identity function. This step is difficult to predict, so I seek a metric which let's me know that the function no longer induces an update.

Comment: So basically you are looking for a termination criteria?

Comment: Ultimately, yes. But this termination criterion must be built on some measure of how close the latest operation is to the identity function.

Comment: So I have very limited knowledge on Bayesian smoothing, but I would assume, there is some measure of information gain is it?

Comment: Each data set is a point in time? The samples in the dataset are a portion of a population? Are the samples to be treated as unique or are they representative of a whole?

Comment: FloLie: Yes, but that information gain is difficult and imprecise to estimate. Quantifying the change in the samples is much easier. @wwii: Not quite, the samples in both data sets correspond to one another. The function which takes X1 to X2 may shift these points around. Or not. =)

Comment: Is an euclidean distance function applicable to your data, so simply speaking (X2-X1)/X1?

Comment: @FloLie: I can measure pairwise distances between samples in X2 and X1, but a division by X1 is not a good idea, as my samples can have an offset. An advantage of a correlation coefficient (or a multi-dimensional equivalent) is that the metric would be scale-independent. A termination criterion based on distance moved wouldn't be, I'm afraid.